# triangular range search in CGAL

Tags: cgal

Im new to CGAL, and I wanted to test the "triangular range search" feature.
Actually, I am puzzled by the example given here:

http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Point_set_2/index.html#Chapter_2D_Range_and_Neighbor_Search

and its results:

> circular range search !
>   5 6
>   6.7 3.8
>   2 11
>   11 20
>   12 14
>   triangular range search !
>   2 11
>   isorectangular range search !
>   -10 -10
>   -5 6
>   2 11

Why the triangular range search does find only one point inside the triangle? (p3)
I was expected it to find at least p1 and p2 as well, as they are part of the triangle.

Thanks for your help,

Thomas.